# How to handle future completion without explicit handling of non-Exception Throwables

Tags: scala, akka, future, throwable

The pattern I keep using for handling `Future` completions inside of *Akka* looks something like this:

```
val caller = sender()
doSomethingAsync().onComplete {
  case Success(arg) => caller ! SuccessMsg(arg)
  case Failure(e:Exception) => caller ! FailureMsg()
  case Failure(e) => throw e // so as to not catch a non-exception Throwable
}
```

I know i'd much rather `map` the future and not use `onComplete`, but mixing `Future` and *Message passing* semantics kind of leads you to a place where you end up at a side-effecting operation.

If i leave the `Failure(e)` case out, I get a warning that my pattern matching will fail, but it's tedious to have to match for the thing I know i shouldn't be catching. Is there a better way to handle success and appropriate failure?

Comment: Fatal errors won't appear in a `Failure`; would handling non-fatal `Error` instances (e.g. `AssertionError`) identically to `Exception`s be a viable approach here?

Comment: It would still warn that my pattern match is not exhaustive :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pipeTo` to send a message from a `Future` to an Actor. You can combine it with [`Future.recover`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@recover[U%3E:T]%28pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U]%29%28implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[U]) to handle the `Failure` case.

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

doSomethingAsync()
  .map(SuccessMsg)
  .recover{ case e: Exception => FailureMsg() }
  .pipeTo(caller)
```